# Autofill information Rails Signup Form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a User table in Rails with a `t.string   "type"`. When users sign up from an specific button, I'd like to automatically fill the table with an specific string.

What's the best way to do this?? I tried HTML but it didn't work.

Thank you

Comment: Please post some code showing a minimal example of what you tried and how it didn't work.  We'll be able to help you better if we see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume this is the link

#### Link

```
=link_to signup_url(signup_source: 'button') # we are sending a query param with it
```

In the signup form will add a field

#### Form

```
=form_for @user do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :signup_source, value: params[:signup_source]
  # Other fields
```

#### controller

```
def create
  #Some stuff
  signup_source = params[:user][:signup_source] # => button
  #Some stuff
end
```

You can store it in the database or whatever you wish